# Ideal of an algebraic set

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $k=\overline{k}$ and $X\subset \mathbb{A}^2_k$ be the algebraic set $V(y(y-x^2))$, i.e. the $x$-axis union a parabola. What is $I(X)\subset k[x,y]$, i.e. what is the radical ideal of $(y^2-x^2y)$?

Comment: So $V(y(y-x^2))=V(y)\cup V(y-x^2)$. Now take $I(-)$. You see $\sqrt{y^2-x^2y)}=(y)\cap(y-x^2)$ which corresponds to radical of primary decomposition of $(y(y-x^2))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: This follows from the fact that $k[x,y]$ is a UFD and $y^2 - x^2 y = y(y - x^2)$ is squarefree.  Let $I = (y^2 - x^2 y)$ and suppose $f \in \sqrt{I}$.  Then $f^m \in I$ for some $m$.  Let $f = u p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_t^{e_t}$ be the prime factorization of $f$.  Then $y$ and $y - x^2$ divide $f^m = u p_1^{m e_1} \cdots p_t^{m e_t}$.  Can you show that we must have $y = p_i$ and $y - x^2 = p_j$ for some $i$ and $j$?  Try to use the fact that $y$ and $y - x^2$ are prime.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing we'll use is $k$ is an infinite domain. 
Note that $V(y(y-x^2)) = V(y) \cup V(y-x^2)$. Now $V(y) = \{ (t,0)\mid t \in k\}$ and $V(y-x^2)= \{(t, t^2) \mid t \in k \}$.

Let $P(x,y) \in k[x,y]$. Divide it by $(y-x^2)$ and get 
$$P(x,y)= (y-x^2) Q(x,y) + R(x)$$
Assume that $P$ is zero on $V(y-x^2)$. This is equivalent to $R(t) = 0$, for all $t \in k$, which means $R(x)\equiv 0$. Therefore, $P(x,y) = (y-x^2)Q(x,y)$. Assume moreover, that $P$ is also $0$ on $V(y)$. That means 
$P(t,0) =0$ for all $t\in k$, that is $(0-t^2)Q(t,0)= 0$ for all $t\in k$. This means $Q(x,0)\equiv 0$, and so $Q(x,y) = y S(x,y)$. We get 
$$P(x,y) = y(y-x^2) S(x,y)$$
Therefore, the ideal of $X$ is $y(y-x^2)$.

We haven't used Nullstellensatz. This works over any infinite domain, for instance $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{R}$.